# Android app crashes as soon as it starts

Tags: java, android, crash, double, calculator

If this is a dumb question then I apologize:

This is my first attempt at making an android app, and for some reason this will not start. It always closes as soon as I click on it Any thoughts on what might be going wrong? I'm lost.

```
package weight.Lifting.stuff;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   
TextView weight100, weight95, weight90, weight85, weight80, weight75, weight70, weight65, weight60;
    EditText enterWeight, enterReps;

    double Weight=1,Reps=1,a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,e=1,f=1,g=1,h=1,i=1,A=.95,B=.90,C=.85,D=.80,E=.75,F=.70,G=.65,H=.60,I=.333;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity__lifting);

        weight100 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView3);
        weight95 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView8);
        weight90 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView9);
        weight85 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView10);
        weight80 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView11);
        weight75 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView12);
        weight70 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView15);
        weight65 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView16);
        weight60 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView17);

        enterWeight = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        enterReps = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
    }



            public void onButton1Click (View v)
            {

                Weight = Double.parseDouble(enterWeight.getText().toString());
                Reps = Double.parseDouble(enterReps.getText().toString());

                a = ((Weight*I*Reps)+Weight);
                b = ((Weight*I*Reps)+Weight)*A;
                c = ((Weight*I*Reps)+Weight)*B;
                d = ((Weight*I*Reps)+Weight)*C;
                e = ((Weight*I*Reps)+Weight)*D;
                f = ((Weight*I*Reps)+Weight)*E;
                g = ((Weight*I*Reps)+Weight)*F;
                h = ((Weight*I*Reps)+Weight)*G;
                i = ((Weight*I*Reps)+Weight)*H;

                weight100.setText(Double.toString(a));
                weight95.setText(Double.toString(b));
                weight90.setText(Double.toString(c));
                weight85.setText(Double.toString(d));
                weight80.setText(Double.toString(e));
                weight75.setText(Double.toString(f));
                weight70.setText(Double.toString(g));
                weight65.setText(Double.toString(h));
                weight60.setText(Double.toString(i));
            }
    }
```

heres my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity_Lifting" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Enter Weight:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Enter Reps:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"
        android:onClick="onButton1Click"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="58dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="95% (3 reps)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="90% (5 reps)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="85% (6 reps)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="100% (1 rep)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
        android:text="70% (12 reps)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:text="65% (15 reps)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView100"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
        android:text="60% (20 reps)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="75% (10 reps)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView100"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="80% (8 reps)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView100"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView100"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView13"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView16"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*edit* added manifest xml and log cat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="weight.Lifting.stuff"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name="weight.Lifting.stuff.MainActivity_Lifting"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat output:

```
02-01 01:49:15.962: W/Trace(785): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-01 01:49:15.962: W/Trace(785): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-01 01:49:15.983: W/dalvikvm(785): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{weight.Lifting.stuff/weight.Lifting.stuff.MainActivity_Lifting}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "weight.Lifting.stuff.MainActivity_Lifting" on path: /data/app/weight.Lifting.stuff-1.apk
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "weight.Lifting.stuff.MainActivity_Lifting" on path: /data/app/weight.Lifting.stuff-1.apk
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
02-01 01:49:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
```

Comment: You should really check the text before you use it. If its empty, ignore the operation. Also look up the dev site about logcat, it typically shows you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your project, it compiles and runs with no issues. Check your AndroidManifest.xml for problems. Consider posting that along with your LogCat output.

Comment: Well at least I know it runs.I don't see anything in the manifest that looks like an error, but I posted it along with the log cat output.

Answer (score 0):

The `parseDouble` methods probably throw an exception when you try to use them, since your EditText  fields are empty/ filled with String. But next time, show the logcat please :D

Comment: I added the logcat to the main question.